# background-clip: text not working with transformed child elements

Tags: css

I'm trying to use `background-clip: text` while also having transformed child elements inside the element with the background, but as soon as I add `transform` (or `position: relative` - I'm sure more things too) to the children `background-clip: text` seizes to work.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to get around it?

```js
document.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  this.classList.toggle('alt');
});
```

```css
h1 {
  background: red;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

h1.alt span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(1rem);
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>H</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span>
</h1>

<p>Click the heading to change the spans from no transform to transform.</p>
```

Comment: note that it works in Firefox

Comment: That's true! Hopefully Firefox are in the right here and Chrome/Safari will follow suit eventually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: transform scale not working with background clip and gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75012797/css-transform-scale-not-working-with-background-clip-and-gradients)