# CSS: transform scale not working with background clip and gradients

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to apply transformation to a div. Using `transform: scale(-1,1)` with a text that has the `background-clip: text` property. But doing so causes the text to disappear. Here is what I've done -

```css
.reverse {
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}

.gradient {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  --bg-size: 400%;
  --color-one: hsl(15 90% 55%);
  --color-two: hsl(40 95% 55%);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: clamp(3rem, 25vmin, 8rem);
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, var(--color-one), var(--color-two), var(--color-one)) 0 0 / var(--bg-size) 100%;
  color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .boujee-text {
    animation: move-bg 8s linear infinite;
  }
  @keyframes move-bg {
    to {
      background-position: var(--bg-size) 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
  <div>H</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div class="reverse">L</div>
  <div>L</div>
  <div>O</div>
</div>
```

The above code works fine, but when the `reverse` class is added, the div disappears.

Output without the `reverse` class:

[image: Without the reverse class]

Output with the `reverse` class

[image: with the reverse class]

Any idea as to what is happening? I'm not sure if the `background-clip` is the issue or the animations. Would appreciate any resources that can help! Thank you!

Comment: Works as expected in Firefox; you may want to use `-webkit-background-clip` in the others. https://caniuse.com/background-clip-text

Comment: @Kosh tired that, didn't work! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a Blink + Webkit bug, it's already been [reported on Chromium's tracker](https://crbug.com/1352821), though it doesn't seem any dev had a look at it yet.
In all fairness, they do still prefix this property, so it's kind of expected quirks like that happen.

Note that it's not only `transform` that does that, but anything that will make the inner element have its own [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) will prevent the text from being used in the clipping rule.

To workaround that issue in these browsers, you'd need to set the background on the transformed `<div>` too. To have it positioned correctly, you can set its `background-attachment` property to `fixed` (You may want to adjust the position after that, I left it to the default).

```css
.reverse {
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}

.gradient {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  --bg-size: 400%;
  --color-one: hsl(15 90% 55%);
  --color-two: hsl(40 95% 55%);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: clamp(3rem, 25vmin, 8rem);
}
.gradient > div {
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, var(--color-one), var(--color-two), var(--color-one)) 0 0 / var(--bg-size) 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .boujee-text > div {
    animation: move-bg 8s linear infinite;
  }
  @keyframes move-bg {
    to {
      background-position: var(--bg-size) 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient boujee-text">
  <div>H</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div class="reverse">L</div>
  <div>L</div>
  <div>O</div>
</div>
```

Comment: background-attachment: fixed; is not compatible with background-clip: text [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment]

Comment: @o17tH1H'S'k and yet it works, doesn't it? Not sure where this MDN article got that from nor what it really implies (I didn't check the specs yet).  Do you know by chance?

Comment: @o17tH1H'S'k I opened https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/26445